# Appropriate choice of method (and stage) of NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to numerically solve a differential equation by using *NDSolve*, the equation looks like the following 
$$\frac{dr}{dr_*}=A(r)$$
I need to obtain the function $r=r(r_*)$ (not the inverse function $r_*=r_*(r)$). Now $A(r)$ is non-negative-definite with $A(r_0)=A(r_1)=0$. In fact, the resulting function $r(r_*)$ looks somewhat similar to the *arctan()* with $-\infty < r_* < +\infty$, $r(-\infty)=r_0$ and $r(+\infty)=r_1$.

The problem is as follows. Being an polynomial, the explicit form of the expression of $A(r)$ is quite complicated. (I tried to insert the definition of the function in this post, but then it turned out to exceed the 30000 character limit, so I have to upload it [here](http://spherio.eel.usp.br/didatico/download/zzz%20-%20tortoise%20coordinate%20NDSolve%20problem.nb).) In the *nb* script, the function $A(r)$ is defined as $$A(r)=B3(r)=\sqrt{f(r)h(r)}$$. I tried to use the *NDSolve* command to find the desired function as follows:

```
B3[r_] = FullSimplify[Sqrt[f[r] h[r]], Assumptions -> {r0 < r < r1}] ;
s3 = NDSolve[{rI'[rS] == B3[rI[rS]], rI[0] == 128/100},rI[rS], {rS, -500, 500}, \
WorkingPrecision -> 100, AccuracyGoal -> 25, PrecisionGoal -> 50]
rR3[rS_] = rI[rS] /. s3[[1]];
```

where the function to be solved is $r(r_*)=rR3(r_*)$. However, *mathematica* was only able to find solution for the interval $(-500,84)$, and I need at least the interval $(-500,500)$. I tried manually all the options found in the manual but was not able get a bigger interval. Any comment or suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: With the current setting, the error message says "the maximum number of steps (MaxSteps) 10000 has reached". I did tried a bigger number MaxSteps -> 1000000, it takes much longer to give the same error message. The point where the integral does not diverge is slightly bigger than 84. But theoretically, I understand the the integral can be carried out til $+\infty$.

Comment: Are you saying that the `DSolve` solution diverges around 84?  If so, either your problem is stiff (if so, try `Method->"StifnessSwitching"`, which might help) or the ODE itself is singular there.  You also could try using `NIntegate` to obtain `rs` as a function of `r` and invert it numerically.

Comment: As I understand the problem is stiffness, thanks a lot for the hints, will try them!

Comment: Just to confirm that both methods work. StiffnessSwitching works like a charm! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the solution suggested by *bbgodfrey*, the problem is due to the stiffness of the function to be integrated. *NDSolve* works out perfectly by using the following method

```
s1 = NDSolve[{rI'[rS] == B3[rI[rS]], rI[0] == 128/100}, 
 rI[rS], {rS, rStarmin, rStarmax}, WorkingPrecision -> 100, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 25, PrecisionGoal -> 50, Method -> StiffnessSwitching];
```

To understand the cause of the problem leads directly to its solution. Much to learn!